# Are there alternative ways to deal with quest Diamond City Blues?

Tags: fallout-4

So the guy walks into a bar...

This quest turns from "my wife is cheating on me, help me talk some sense into guy who sleeps with her" to "go and kill drug dealers, even if the deal itself is legal". I don't like that. I'd like to leave it alone, or to go and tell them "hey, this guy was planning to turn on you and get you killed, but I won't. He's dead, can we be friends now?".

So my question is two-fold:

1. Will game give me a chance not to fight them if I'll go there?
2. If not, how can I get rod of the quest from my Pip-Boy? And preferably not to trigger automatically if I'll go there by accident?

Answer (score 1):

1. The ambush will always happen, but you don't have to kill any
   named characters, but it is possible they get themselves killed by
   who ever you decided to do the ambush with. ([Nelson Latimer](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Nelson_Latimer) is
   the only named NPC that can die by accident, to avoid that make sure
   you to "kill" [Trish](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Trish_(Fallout_4)) as fast as possible, she can't die and it
   ends to battle if she id downed)
2. The ambush will only become a fight after a dialog or if you open
   fire on them.

Comment: From what I recall you can also get a follow-up quest from one of the named characters if you don't kill them. Might want to save before engaging if you are curious about the options.